# Create system call to run my python code in jsp file

Tags: java, python, jsp, user-interface, html

What I'm trying to do is to create a jsp page that would call my Python code. I'm trying to call my Python code as a system function in jsp. I'm creating this page to make a cross domain call to this page from another jsp page.

Can anyone tell me how can I make a system call for my Python code?
I run the following command for the execution of my Python code in the terminal:

```
root@user:/folder # python p111.py
```

i tried the following code

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now 
<script>
Process qq=Runtime.exec(new String[] { "./dsapce/webapps/jspui/p111.py", "p111.py", }, null, new File("./dsapce/webapps/jspui/p111.py"));
qq.waitFor();
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

something not correct..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java's [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29), or [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) if you need something fancier.

But also look into Jython. It lets you run Python code *in* Java.

And avoid putting business logic in JSPs; it's generally frowned upon—they're better for templating. Put forwarding code like that in a `Servlet`.

Here's an example, but you have to make sure `python` can be found. You might have to put an absolute path in rather than just `"python"`:

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] { "python", "p111.py", }, null, new File("./path/where/p111/lives"));
```

If Java isn't running as root (which it shouldn't be), but Python has to (which is probably shouldn't), something like this would be better, but it's OS-dependent:

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] { "sudo", "python", "p111.py", }, null, new File("./path/where/p111/lives"));
```

These return a `Process` object. If you want to wait for Python to finish and see if the operation was a success, do `process.waitFor()` and check the value. If you want to grab the output or provide input, you'll need to do `process.getInput/Output/ErrorStream()`.

If this script runs frequently and completes quickly and you care about performance, this is a bad model because process creation is expensive.

Comment: ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("root@user:/folder # python p111.py"); will work? or Runtime.getRuntime().exec("root@user:/folder # python p111.py"); will work?

Comment: '   <HTML>
   <BODY>
   Hello!  The time is now 
   <script>
   Process qq=Runtime.exec(new String[] { "./dsapce/webapps/jspui/p111.py", "p111.py", }, null, new File("./dsapce/webapps/jspui    /p111.py"));
   qq.waitFor();
   </script>
   </BODY>
  </HTML>'                                                                                                    this is my jsp code, but the python file is not executing.

Comment: `<script>` is Javascript, not JSP. It's run client-side, and has absolutely nothing to do with Java (or JSP). If you want this to run server-side, before the client loads the page, use `<% ... %>`. If you want something client-side, that's a completely different thing. What are you *really* trying to do, here, with `p111.py`?

Comment: im getting an error 'File cannot be resolved to a type' on Runtime.exec(... line, wat can be the reason?